# Función para aplicar estilo a elemento hijo, haciendo clic desde el padre

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Tengo la siguiente estructura, donde (omitiendo la clase `.m-2`) `.drop__card` sería el elemento padre y `.circulo` uno de los elementos hijo.

```
<div class="m-2">
      <div class="drop__card" onclick="switchColor(this);"> <!-- PADRE -->
        <div class="drop__data">
          <div>
            <p class="fw-bold m-0">TITULO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circulo"> <!-- HIJO -->
          <h2>HIJO</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Al hacer clic en el card, la función `switchColor` me cambia el color de fondo de la misma:

```js
let estadoColor;

function switchColor(el) {
  if (estadoColor) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = estadoColor;
    estadoColor = null;
  } else {
    estadoColor = el.style.backgroundColor;
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#e35d6a';
  }
}
```

```css
.drop__card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.circulo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cecece;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.circulo>h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container my-5">

  <div class="m-2 ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="drop__card d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border rounded shadow-sm p-2" onclick="switchColor(this);">
      <div class="drop__data">
        <div>
          <p class="fw-bold m-0">VIERNES</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo">
        <h2>5</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m-2 ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="drop__card d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border rounded shadow-sm p-2" onclick="switchColor(this);">
      <div class="drop__data">
        <div>
          <p class="fw-bold m-0">SABADO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo">
        <h2>6</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m-2 ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="drop__card d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border rounded shadow-sm p-2" onclick="switchColor(this);">
      <div class="drop__data">
        <div>
          <p class="fw-bold m-0">DOMINGO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo">
        <h2>7</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Lo que necesito es aplicar esta función únicamente al hijo, es decir la clase `.circulo`

Si cambio la posición del *onclick* dentro del elemento hijo, funciona.

```
<div class="m-2">
      <div class="drop__card"> <!-- PADRE -->
        <div class="drop__data">
          <div>
            <p class="fw-bold m-0">TITULO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circulo" onclick="switchColor(this);"> <!-- HIJO -->
          <h2>HIJO</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Pero necesito que funcione haciendo clic desde el padre, que por tamaño y comodidad, sería el primero en dar clic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que buscar la clase circulo dentro del padre

```
let circulo = el.querySelector(".circulo");
```

```js
let estadoColor;

function switchColor(el) {
  let circulo = el.querySelector(".circulo");
  if (estadoColor) {
    circulo.style.backgroundColor = estadoColor;
    estadoColor = null;
  } else {
    estadoColor = circulo.style.backgroundColor;
    circulo.style.backgroundColor = '#e35d6a';
  }
}
```

```css
.drop__card {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.circulo {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cecece;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

.circulo>h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container my-5">

  <div class="m-2 ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="drop__card d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border rounded shadow-sm p-2" onclick="switchColor(this);">
      <div class="drop__data">
        <div>
          <p class="fw-bold m-0">VIERNES</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo">
        <h2>5</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m-2 ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="drop__card d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border rounded shadow-sm p-2" onclick="switchColor(this);">
      <div class="drop__data">
        <div>
          <p class="fw-bold m-0">SABADO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo">
        <h2>6</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="m-2 ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="drop__card d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between border rounded shadow-sm p-2" onclick="switchColor(this);">
      <div class="drop__data">
        <div>
          <p class="fw-bold m-0">DOMINGO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="circulo">
        <h2>7</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Mil gracias capo! Una última, perdon que no estaba originalmente planteada: si quisiera regresar al color original (gris), es posible al hacer clic de nuevo?

Comment: @Alvamon6 Crea otra pregunta y te la respondo

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/556821/update-sql-al-presionar-evento-onclick Más enfocada a AJAX, PHP MySQL pero a lo mejor podrías darme una mano, gracias